# create CvMat from a C++ vector of CvPoint2D32f

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am trying to create a CvMat data structure using cvMat() in OpenCV.

The last parameter of cvMat() expects a void* to the data.

My data is stored in the following data structure

```
vector<vector<CvPoint2D32f>> data;
```

I expected

```
data.at(0)
```

to work as the last parameter, but the compiler says that it can not convert to void*.

What path should I be taking now ?

Create an array from vectors ? That would waste a lot of time/memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data.at(0) has `vector<CvPoint2D32f>` type, but you need **pointer** to the **first element** of that vector. Try:

```
 &(data.at(0).at(0))
```

Also keep in mind, that `vector<vector<CvPoint2D32f>>` is not a two dimensional array of CvPoint2D32f. It is more like "vector of references" to one dimensional arrays.

Comment: Hm, I don't remember why I gave this answer. Maybe there was something more in the question before, that made me think that author wanted to convert only first vector.